# Where to add maps for different logic app in same Visual Studio Code project?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have one visual studio code project in which I have two logic apps.
Both logic apps have their own XSLT mapping files.
I know that I can add the mapping files to `workflows/Artifacts/Maps` for the mapping files to deploy to Azure.
However, what folder structure should I use to deploy certain mapping files only to logic app 1 and other mapping files only to logic app 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Need to create two different projects in Vs code *(for example **Project Logicapp1** and **Project Logicapp2**)* to deploy mapping file only to **Logicapps1** and other mapping files only to **Logicapps2**.

Then you can map your mapping files in each project `Project Logicapp1/Artifacts/Maps`  and  `Project Logicapp2/Artifacts/Maps`.

Then You need to deploy each project folder separately to corresponding Logic apps. deploy **Project Logicapp1** to **Logicapps1** and **Project Logicapp2** to **Logicapps2**. Then Each of the Logic have their own Mapping files respectively.

I have tried reproducing you situation in My Environment.
In VS code deploying multiple Logic Apps in a one Project. I have created two logic apps named **"Statefultes"** and **"Statelesstest"** in Project **NEW LOGIC APPS** as show below:

[image]

As You can see the Artifact folder remains single. There is no separate folder for each logic apps as show below:

[image]

After deploying to Azure my both logic apps workflow is deployed as shown below:
[image]

And in the **Map** section under **Artifacts**:

[image]